# Angular-cli/webpack cannot find module when Component Metadata is given by a factory

Tags: angular, webpack, factory, angular-cli

I'm trying to create a component using a metadata factory such as follows:

`@Component(MetadataFactory.Create(module.id))`

which returns:

```
public static Create(moduleId: string): Component
    {
        return {
            selector: "dummy-selector,
            templateUrl: "./DummyView.html"
        };
}
```

But I get the following error:

[image]

It seems that it is trying to find the templateUrl path in the factory folder, which is not the desired behaviour.

Has anyone found a way to work with this?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me with this setup, angular 2 and angular-cli 1.0.0

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

class Util {
    static  Create = (moduleId: string): Component => {
        return {
            selector: 'test-selector',
            templateUrl: './test.html',
        };
    }
}
@Component(Util.Create(module.id))
export class Test {
  constructor() { }
}
```

Comment: What if the create method is in another folder, could you please test? Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide a sample repo? What if the templateUrl is not directly in the return? like, templateUrl: this.getTemplateUrl()

Comment: here is a example, look at `util.ts` and `heros.component.ts` https://plnkr.co/edit/W3oLuf1PtYCmWCcNUd9L?p=preview

as for the `templateUrl: this.getTemplateUrl()` it does not work, try it with any component in the plunkr above

Comment: It works because the files are all in the same level, could you please try adding a folder util and place the util.ts inside? I tried in the plunkr and I got: zone.js@0.8.4:571 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load app/util/heroes.component.html.

Comment: ha, this is interesting, if you move the `util.ts` anywhere, the paths are relative to the `util.ts` file and not where the `create` function is called (the `heros.component.ts` in this case). I tested that in local, same thing. you might want to figure out how to do the path resolution or look for a solution that does it for you pre angular-cli ts transpile and build.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that someone had had this problem before, but I guess not.. For now I've fixed it by appending the templateUrl and styleUrls to the create return directly in the component file. Will look into it, if you get anything let me know! :) Thanks